# Why are my waiting times for ttfb so long when using Local IIS?

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, iis, localhost

Despite performance tests throughout my server consistently returning results of ~50ms, any call to controller methods in my c# code using angularjs (1.4) or jquery (1.9.1) produce inconsistent ttfb times. Sometimes they will successfully return the data in less than 100ms whereas other times the ttfb will reach upwards of 1.5s. I have also individually tested calling the controller methods through my browser (cache was disabled) and data returned was lightening quick (less than ~50ms).

Calling my controller:

```
$http.get(baseUrl + "Home/AnnouncementsPartial", { params: { startIndex: 
$scope.startIndex, numberMessages: $scope.numberMessages, resetSearch: reset 
} }).success(function (data) {
```

Waterfall demonstration:

[image]

I am running on localhost so knowing that my controller methods return data in ~50ms, I would expect the ttfb times to be under 100ms at least. Any help much appreciated

Comment: If you're running in debug, that'll always be slower. Another consideration is the time from last activity. If you've left it inactive for a while, IIS will close the host process only to spin it up again on the next request

Comment: I ran on both release and debug. However they both returned similar waiting times. yes, I have noticed IIS does this however even after recent requests it has a long ttfb

Comment: What caching policy is configured for the content files? Do you have compression enabled (static or dynamic)?

Comment: I'm looking in more detail on the screenshot and the longest times there all seem to be server side, i.e., that the server is taking time to actually run code rather than pull down a static file - is this correct or am I misreading?

Comment: Thanks for all your input DiskJunky, I have disabled cache browser side for testing purposes. Objective of this was to decrease loading time of the messages so enabling cache browser side would produce false-positive results. I am not sure about compression, let me get back to you on that one. The server isn't taking long to run the code, when I time the methods from start to finish, they execute in ~50ms. Seems like it may be a problem with the way IIS is handling the connections.

Comment: If you have a lot of connections, browsers will generally just run 2 concurrent connections at a time. However, if this is just loading text, would it not make more sense to include it in the initial HTML in hidden blocks? That way there are no dynamic calls to the server as it's all pre-loaded in the initial drop.

Comment: I do not have compression enabled. Also forgot to mention, I do cache server side. Conditions when it caches is when there has been no update to the database or 5 days have not passed yet since last cache. I have tested server side cache and it works as expected

Comment: Also the content loading is dynamic, it is a request made to the server which then loads the most recent messages from the database and sends it back. So I wouldn't be able to include it in the initial html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155076/discussion-between-user3918443-and-diskjunky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this one was what DiskJunky mentioned in the comments section, there is a maximum number of concurrent requests that a web browser can handle in one connection until it starts to generate new requests sequentially. For this scenario, I structured my code slightly differently so my higher priority requests were executed first and therefore ran concurrently with each other.